# Getting view in a preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

When a button is clicked we get a view in the onClickListener method. Like:

```
Button btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    quickAction.show(v);
            }});
```

How can we do the same with the Preference i.e, if i want to pass the View of the preference screen to some method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to finding a preference in a PreferenceFragment/PreferenceActivity you can do

```
Preference myPreference = findPreference("preference_key");
myPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
    {

        return false;
    }
});
```

You won't be able to get a view in the traditional sense of how you're thinking but you will instead get a Preference object. You can call `getView (View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` on the preference, however.

Comment: Thanks for replying but can you tell what should be parameters in the getView() method by giving an example, as i am unable to understand this method

Comment: for your case you can pass null into both.  View view = myPreference.getView(null, null);  for a description of what they're used for check out the documentation for Preferences here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html scroll down to getView.. sorry, for whatever reason I can't link directly to that method